# Django model: create a new column based on the division of two other column

Tags: django-models, view

Hello everyone I have the following model.py:

```
 class Plant(models.Model)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    chair_size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I need a third column which has the total number of chairs which is equal to size/chair_size. e.g.

```
chair_number=size/chair_size
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the times you find the answer once you post the question:

my answer is:

```
def chair_number(self):
    return (self.size)/self.chair_size 
number_chair=property(chair_number)
```